# I'd like to create a form dynamically instead of XAML

Tags: c#, forms, xaml, dynamic

I would like to create a form dynamically instead of using the XAML to do it.
The form reside into a tab control. Below is XAML code:

this is a XAML sample.

```
<TabControl>
<TabItem Header="SVRS Data" Name="tab_SVRS_Data2">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="113*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="113*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="55*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="58*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="113*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="13" />
            <RowDefinition Height="24" />
            <RowDefinition Height="15" />
            <RowDefinition Height="24" />
            <RowDefinition Height="24" />
            <RowDefinition Height="24" />
            <RowDefinition Height="24" />
            <RowDefinition Height="5" />
            <RowDefinition Height="24" />
            <RowDefinition Height="24" />
            <RowDefinition Height="5" />
            <RowDefinition Height="24" />
            <RowDefinition Height="24" />
            <RowDefinition Height="24" />
            <RowDefinition Height="24" />
            <RowDefinition Height="5" />
            <RowDefinition Height="24" />
            <RowDefinition Height="24" />
            <RowDefinition Height="24" />
            <RowDefinition Height="5" />
            <RowDefinition Height="24" />
            <RowDefinition Height="5" />
            <RowDefinition Height="24" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Name="btn_SaveSVRSDataDyn" Content="Save" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="1"  ToolTip="Saves the changes to the SVRS data " FontWeight="Bold" Click="btn_SaveSVRSData_Click" />

        <TextBox Name="SVRS_OuterEnvelopeId2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource InputBoxes}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
        <Label Content="Outer Enveloppe ID" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource LabelsOverlay}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="5,0" />

        <TextBox Name="SVRS_LastName2" Grid.Row="3" Style="{StaticResource InputBoxes}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Uid="Elector"/>
        <Label Content="Last Name" Grid.Row="3" Style="{StaticResource LabelsOverlay}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="5,0"/>

        <TextBox Name="SVRS_FirstName2" Grid.Row="4" Style="{StaticResource InputBoxes}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Uid="Elector"/>
        <Label Content="First Name" Grid.Row="4" Style="{StaticResource LabelsOverlay}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="5,0"/>

        <TextBox Name="SVRS_MiddleName2" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" Style="{StaticResource InputBoxes}" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Uid="Elector" Margin="1" />
        <Label Content="Middle Name" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" Style="{StaticResource LabelsOverlay}" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="5,0"/>

        <TextBox Name="SVRS_DaytimePhoneNumber2" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="4" Style="{StaticResource InputBoxes}" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Uid="Elector" Margin="1" />
        <Label Content="Daytime Phone" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="4" Style="{StaticResource LabelsOverlay}" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="5,0"/>

        <ComboBox Name="SVRS_GenderTypeCode2" Grid.Row="5"  Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxes}" Uid="Elector"/>
        <Label Content="Gender" Grid.Row="5" Style="{StaticResource LabelsOverlay}"/>

        <TextBox Name="SVRS_DOB2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5"  Style="{StaticResource InputBoxes}" Uid="Elector" MaxLength="10" CharacterCasing="Upper" DataContext="{Binding}" LostFocus="SVRS_DOB_LostFocus" />
        <Label Content="DOB" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" Style="{StaticResource LabelsOverlay}"/>

        <TextBox Name="SVRS_EveningPhoneNumber2" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="5" Style="{StaticResource InputBoxes}" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Uid="Elector" Margin="1" />
        <Label Content="Evening Phone" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="5" Style="{StaticResource LabelsOverlay}" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="5,0"/>

        <ComboBox Name="SVRS_Language2" Grid.Row="6"  Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxes}" Uid="Elector"/>
        <Label Content="Language" Grid.Row="6" Style="{StaticResource LabelsOverlay}"/>

        <TextBox Name="SVRS_EmailAddress2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="6" Style="{StaticResource InputBoxes}" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Uid="Elector" Margin="1" />
        <Label Content="email" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="6" Style="{StaticResource LabelsOverlay}" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Margin="5,0"/>
    </Grid>
</TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "create a form dynamically"? The XAML is already dynamic, if you consider dynamic as data-driven so that the code does not need to be recompiled to change the layout.

Comment: i wan to genarate de form layout dynamically, all the labels and textfields

Comment: I think he means at run-time, not at design-time. If that's the case, I don't recommend doing that if it can be avoided. It just makes it annoying to debug and adjust visually, at least in my experience. What is your reason for doing it this way, if I may ask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean that you want to generate these controls by code at runtime, then the following snippet will give you an idea:

```
        // Define grid with columns and rows
        var grid = new Grid();
        grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(113, GridUnitType.Star) });
        grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(55, GridUnitType.Star) });
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(13)});
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(24) });

        // Create each control and set its location
        var button = new Button { Name = "ButtonName", Content = "Button Content" };
        grid.Children.Add(button);
        Grid.SetColumn(button, 0);
        Grid.SetRow(button, 0);

        var textBox = new TextBox { Name= "TextBoxName"};
        grid.Children.Add(textBox);
        Grid.SetColumn(textBox, 1);
        Grid.SetRow(textBox, 0);

        // Create the tab control and add items
        var tabItem = new TabItem {Header = "Sample Header", Name = "TabName", Content = grid};

        var tabControl = new TabControl();
        tabControl.Items.Add(tabItem);

        MyWindow.AddChild(tabControl);
```

Comment: Thank's Bro. this helped me understand